# Parsing left associative in Haskell for only some operations

Tags: parsing, haskell, functional-programming, monads

I am trying to make a parser that will be able to parse expressions such as `2<3` succesfully as `Oper Less (Const (IntVal 2)) (Const (IntVal 3))` while at the same time failing parseing chains such as `2 < 3 < 4` while also at the same time still being able to parse succesfully `2+2 < 5`. I have tried to use `chainl1` to keep my operations left associative for both `+`,`-` and other operations. My problem seems to be with `pOperHelper` and when using `pTerm` in it. It might be because I don't grasp `chainl1` fully. I get the following output

```
ghci> parseString "2 < 3 < 4"
Left "Unexpected error"
ghci> parseString "2 < 3"
Right (Oper Less (Const (IntVal 2)) (Const (IntVal *** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

for the MVE below:

```
module MVEParser (ParseError, parseString, pOper, pOperHelper, pTerm, pExpr) where

import Data.Char

import Text.ParserCombinators.ReadP
import Control.Applicative ((<|>))


type ParseError = String -- you may replace this

type Parser a = ReadP a 

data Value =
  IntVal Int
  deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

data Op = Plus | Minus | Less | Greater 
  deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

data Exp =
    Const Value
  | Oper Op Exp Exp
  deriving (Eq, Show, Read)

space :: Parser Char
space = satisfy isSpace

spaceBeforeAfter :: String -> Parser String
spaceBeforeAfter x = do spaces; str <- string x; space; return str

spaces :: Parser String 
spaces = many space

symbol :: String -> Parser String
symbol = token . string

token :: Parser a -> Parser a
token combinator = (do spaces
                       combinator)

pExpr :: Parser Exp 
pExpr = {- chainl1 pTerm pOper +++  -}chainl1 pTerm (pOperHelper pOper)

pTerm :: Parser Exp 
pTerm =                      
       (do         
        skipSpaces        
        pv <- munch isDigit
        skipSpaces       
        return (Const (IntVal (read pv))))
       
pOper :: ReadP (Exp -> Exp -> Exp)
pOper = (symbol "+" >> return (Oper Plus))
        <|> (symbol "-" >> return (Oper Minus))
        <|> (symbol "<" >> return (Oper Less))
        <|> (symbol ">" >> return (Oper Greater))
       
pOperHelper :: ReadP (Exp -> Exp -> Exp) -> ReadP (Exp -> Exp -> Exp)
pOperHelper op = do
  operator <- op  
  term <- pTerm  
  skipSpaces
  nextChar  <- look
  case nextChar of
    (c:_) | c `elem` ['<', '>'] -> pfail
    _ -> return operator

parseString input = let x = readP_to_S (do e <- pExpr; token eof; return e) input
                    in case x of                         
                        [(a, "")] -> Right a                                            
                        _ -> Left "Unexpected error"
```

Why is the `Prelude.read` occuring though, and is there a smarter way I can make use of `chainl1` or similar and accomplish what I intend?

Comment: You are treating all 4 operators as if they have the same precedence. `<` and `>` have to have *lower* precedence than `+` and `-`, which means you should use separate non-terminals in your grammar, like `pCompOper` and `pArithOper`, as well as breaking `PTerm` into `PArithTerm` and `PCompTerm`.

Comment: Will this mean that I can't do it with the `chain1l` either?

Comment: Correct. `2 + 2 < 5` still parses "correctly" if you don't adjust the precedence, but `1 < 2 + 2` will not. (With equal precedence, it would be equivalent to `(1 < 2) + 2`, not `1 < (2 + 2)`.)

Comment: `2 < 3 < 4` should fail because `2 < 3` should not be a valid left-hand operand of `<`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chain*` parsers are specifically designed to allow things like `2 < 3 < 4`. What you want is a grammar that *distinguishes* between arithmetic operators and comparison operators. For example, you are currently using a grammar like

```
Expr -> Term (Op Term)+
Term -> Digit +
Op -> '+' | '-' | '<' | '>'
Digit -> '0' | ... | '9'
```

when what you want is something more complicated, which creates comparison operators differently (and with lower precedence) than arithmetic operators. Something like

```
Expr -> ArithTerm (CompOp ArithTerm)+
CompOp -> '<' | '>'
ArithTerm -> ArithTerm (ArithOp NumTerm) | NumTerm
NumTerm -> Digit +
ArithOp -> '+' | '-'
Digit -> '0' | ... | '9'
```

Now `2 < 3 < 4` is not allowed, because neither `2 < 3` nor `3 < 4` is an `ArithTerm`, and so can't appear on one side other of `<`. `1 < 2 + 2` is fine because `1` and `2 + 2` are both `ArithTerm`s.

Comment: That was a good answer. I was however able to implement it with a `chainl1` within the `chainl1` although I had to add some helper functions as well.